# JAVA_HOME IS INVALID (Cordova)

Tags: java, android, cordova

As-salāmu ʿalaykum,

I'm having trouble setting JAVA_HOME correctly.

- I know that the JAVA_HOME needs to be set to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92`
- I know PATH has to be set to`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\bin`

I set both the JAVA_HOME and PATH as a user variable and as a [system variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfh83.png).

When I run Android Studio tells me it's [invalid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLCEz.png).  When I [echo out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaZzj.png) JAVA_HOME, it's set as expected.  Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried setting the variable using quotes `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\bin"` or maybe using the shortcut `C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\bin` to avoid the problems with the space in "Program Files" string?

Comment: I reformatted this question to be a little more clear and to link the images uploaded to specific points.  I converted the greeting As-salāmu ʿalaykum to match Wikipedia's suggestion for spelling.

Comment: You might want to check if **JAVA_HOME** is specified differently somewhere else such as **gradle.properties** file. If that is the case it can override the **JAVA_HOME** value you specified.

Answer (score 6):

- You need to set your JAVA_HOME to: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\`
- And set PATH to: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\bin` so that it can be accessible from cmd
- Then you might need to restart the computer

*Note:*

In some cases **JAVA_HOME** is specified differently somewhere else such as  **gradle.properties** file. In that case, the global value can be overridden by the project's **JAVA_HOME** for that specific project.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention which windows version you are working on. However, you can try to set the JAVA_HOME variable via the command line as an alternate solution.

Open Command Prompt (make sure you Run as administrator so you're able to add a system environment variable).

Set the value of the environment variable to your JDK (or JRE) installation path as follows:

```
setx -m JAVA_HOME "C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_XX"
```

If the path contains spaces, use the shortened path name.

Restart Command Prompt to reload the environment variables then use the following command to check the it's been added correctly.

```
echo %JAVA_HOME%
```

You should see the path to your JDK (or JRE) installation.

Answer (score 0):

Besides defining the path **you need to enable Java in Windows Defender**.

- Hint: **Disable windows defender and firewall** (google it).
- Put in the prompt "java -version" and "javac -version" commands again and have fun.

Sorry, english isn’t my first language.